# How can I return HTML in a Django view?

Tags: python, html, django, matlab-figure

I am trying to display a matlib plot on my browser, I’m using Django. So far I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import base64
from io import BytesIO

fig = plt.figure()
#plot sth

tmpfile = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(tmpfile, format='png')
encoded = base64.b64encode(tmpfile.getvalue())

html = 'Some html head' + '<img src=\'data:image/png;base64,{}\'>'.format(encoded) + 'Some more html'

with open('test.html','w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

However, instead of f.write(html), I want something like:

```
return render_to_response(html)
```

How do I do this with a large html string?

Answer (score 0):

I got it using this library: https://mpld3.github.io/quickstart.html

```
fig = image_compare.get_images_figure()
html = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)

return render(request, 'products/blank.html', {'html' : html})
```

and blank.html looks like this:

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ html }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects)?

```
return HttpResponse("<p>Some html</p>")
```